# Get data from an API with Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have a simple flask app, which is intended to make a request to an api and return data. Unfortunately, I can't share the details, so you can reproduce the error. The app looks like that:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def getData():
    # define variables 
    username = "<username>"
    password = "<password>"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic"}
    reqHeaders = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    payload = json.dumps(
        {
            "jobType": "<jobType>", 
            "jobName": "<jobName>",
            "startPeriod": "<startPeriod>",
            "endPeriod": "<endPeriod>",
            "importMode": "<importMode>",
            "exportMode": "<exportMode>"
        }
    )
    jobId = 7044
    
    req = requests.get("<url>", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), headers=reqHeaders, data=payload)
    return req.content

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However, when executed this returns error 500: *Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

The same script but outside a flask app (just the function as it is defined here) runs with no problems at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

flask app return format json. If you return req.content, it will break function. You must parse response request to json before return it.

```
from flask import jsonify 
return jsonify(req.json())
```

It's better with safe load response when the request fail

```
req = requests.get()
if req.status_code !=200:
   return {}
else:
   return jsonify(req.json())
```